# Create Json file from multiple tables from MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, json, python-2.7, unix, amazon-web-services

I have 2 different tables(Person and sport) in MySQL database. I would like to create a json file from these 2 tables in the following format. Person table has first_name, middle_name and last_name columns and sport table has sport_name and league_name columns. Logically each person may have more than one sport item. Please help me

```
“score”: {
     “ps”:{
        “person”:{
            “first_name”: "fName1"
            “middle_name”: "MName1"
            “last_name”: "Lname1"               
            "sports":{
                "sport":{
                    “sport_name”: "sport1"
                    “league_name”: "legue1"
                }
                "sport":{
                    “sport_name”: "sport2"  
                    “league_name”: "legue2"
                }
             }
        }
        “person”:{
            .......
        }
    }
}
```

---

I tied the following code and answer but I would like to see the sport as sub array
I tried the following code. I would like to have sport as sub array of person.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb
import json
import collections
from collections import defaultdict 
class Dict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, Dict)
    def __repr__(self):
        return dict.__repr__(self) 

db = MySQLdb.connect("Server","userName","pawd","dbName" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT person_id,first_name,last_name,gender FROM scorefoliodev1.person "
cursor.execute(sql)

rows = cursor.fetchall()
objects_list = []
for row in rows:
    d = Dict()
    d["Person"]['person_id'] = row[0]
    d["Person"]['first_name'] = row[1]
    d["Person"]['last_name'] = row[2]
    d["Person"]['gender'] = row[3]
    objects_list.append(d)

j = json.dumps(objects_list, indent=4)
print j
objects_file = 'person_info55.js'
f = open(objects_file,'w')
print >> f,j 
db.close()
```

Answer

```
[
    {
        "Person": {
            "person_id": 111, 
            "gender": "Male", 
            "first_name": "FName1", 
            "last_name": "LName"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "Person": {
            "person_id": 112, 
            "gender": "Male", 
            "first_name": "fname2", 
            "last_name": "lName2"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Updated the question with my code

Comment: Thanks. One more thing I think missing is how your person is related to sport table. Pls explain it better. Hopefully someone from Python community will help you. (Not me)

Comment: Person and sport table related by using "person_id"

Answer (score 0):

The json format allows you to define arrays. You can do something like this:

```
"sports":[
   {
      "sport_name": "sport1",
      "league_name": "legue1"
   },
   {
      "sport_name": "sport2",
      "league_name": "legue2"
   }
]
```

Comment: Frederik, I agree, but my problem is sub array, sport is sub array of person array. I am new to Python and don't know how to create lists to generate json file with sub arrays

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is sub array, sport is sub array of person array. I am new
>   to Python and don't know how to create lists to generate json file
>   with sub arrays

You say: *Person and sport table related by using "person_id"*. So, we can create a dictionary with the sports for the persons. Assume e. g. a `SELECT person_id,sport_name,league_name FROM sport` yields the `rows`

```
   [[111, "sport1", "legue1"],
    [112, "sport2", "legue2"],
    [111, "sport3", "legue3"]]
```

Then we can do

```
sports = {}
for row in rows:
    sport = { "sport_name": row[1], "league_name": row[2] }
    if not row[0] in sports: sports[row[0]] = []
    sports[row[0]].append(sport)
```

and `sports` results in

```
{
    "112": [ { "league_name": "legue2", "sport_name": "sport2" } ], 
    "111": [ { "league_name": "legue1", "sport_name": "sport1" }, 
             { "league_name": "legue3", "sport_name": "sport3" } ]
}
```

so now we have the *sub array*, which we can simply insert into the person `objects_list` you already had:

```
for person in objects_list:
    person["Person"]['sports'] = sports[person["Person"]['person_id']]
```